# How can I pipe stdout to another process, whilst also capturing stdout in a local file?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, io-redirection

With a command as follows:

```bsh
program_that_produces_stdout | program_that_captures_stdout
```

I would like to capture the output of `program_that_produces_stdout` in a file locally too.

Obviously

```bsh
program_that_produces_stdout | program_that_captures_stdout > some_file
```

Doesn't work, and `tee` doesn't appear to be the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tee` is the right command, in the right place.

```
 program_that_produces_stdout | tee some_file | program_that_captures_stdout
```

If you want to append to "some_file", rather than overwrite it (so ">>" rather than ">") then use `tee -a` instead.

e.g.

```
 program_that_produces_stdout | tee -a some_file | program_that_captures_stdout
```